# Magento 2 : sales_order_place_before Observer Event does not stop payment from proceeding

Tags: magento2

I am trying to stop a payment from proceeding if a certain test is not met; the user should then be redirected back to the checkout page with an error message.

I am able to key into the event using

> sales_order_place_before

However, although I am able to revert the person back to checkout page , i am not able to stop the purchase going through.

> here is my code:

the DI

> app/code/Test/Module/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="sales_order_place_before">
       <observer name="order_place_before" instance="Test\Module\Observer\BeforePurchaseValidateAvailability" shared="false" />
    </event>  
</config>
```

**The Class**

> /code/Test/Module/Observer/BeforePurchaseValidateAvailability

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,

        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,
        EventDome  $eventDomeHelper,    
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url    
    ) {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_currency = $currency;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_eventDomeHelper = $eventDomeHelper;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

       try {

            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/stackexchange.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info("success !!!!  Before Purchase Validate  !!!");

            $message = 'it does not work';
            $this->_messageManager->addError($message);

            $checkOutUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($checkOutUrl)->sendResponse();
            return $this;
            die();



        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($exception);
        }
    }
```

The issue:

How do you use an observer to stop a payment from going through ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated solution:**

```
 if(Your_condition)
 {
 }
 else
 {
    $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
          $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
      exit;
 }
```

**NOTE: CODE TESTED**

Comment: HI theSeeker. Did you try this?

Comment: hey buddy. thanks for prompt reply. just testing it now

Comment: ok no prob.. let me know once it resolves.

Comment: hey buddy. it works . but how do u send the user back to a specific page . i tried this: 
        $message = __('Stop the function');
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException($message);
            
              $checkOutUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
         return   $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($checkOutUrl)->sendResponse();

Comment: check my updated answer. It's working fine

Comment: hi. thanks mated. it worked. could you please also help me with this:   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290812/magento-2-how-to-retrieve-custom-quote-params-from-quote-object-after-order

Answer (score 0):

Update your `execute()`  function with this

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

       try {

            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/stackexchange.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info("success !!!!  Before Purchase Validate  !!!");

            $message = 'it does not work';

            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($message));
                return;

        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey buddy. thanks for prompt reply. just testing it now.